# JavaScript Page Load Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I written some code that runs on page load, the objective of the code is to grab all items from a specific drop down menu, store those items in an array and then one by one add those items from the array back into the drop down menu in a customized order.

Here is my problem, on this specific page there are 7 drop down menus, on page load it is doing exactly what it should be doing, it is customizing the order perfectly. Based on the selection the user makes, it filter another drop down. The problem is that I am grabbing the drop down object based on a `has(option:contains())`, this is the problem because the drop down menu being filtered is using the keyword I am grabbing to grab that object.

For example:

My drop down menu contains :

New York

Alabama

Texas

**User chooses New York**

The drop down being filtered would then be filtered to:

New York - Shopping

New York - Nightlife

New York - Sports

The problem is since I am using the `has(option:contains())` and using `New York`, on submit both drop downs are being refiltered and causing an issue...

Here is my code:

```
        var select = $('select:has(option:contains(New York))');
        var options = select.find("option");

        //assigning drop down list items to new variable
        var OptionObj1 = $('select option:contains("None")');
        var OptionObj2 = $('select option:contains("New York")');
        var OptionObj3 = $('select option:contains("Texas")');
        var OptionObj4 = $('select option:contains("Alabama")');
        var OptionObj5 = $('select option:contains("Colorado")');

        //clearing drop down list
        select.empty();

        //adding new items from array into drop down list
        select.append(OptionObj1 [0]);
        select.append(OptionObj2 [0]);
        select.append(OptionObj3 [0]);
        select.append(OptionObj4 [0]);
        select.append(OptionObj5 [0]);
```

I said alot in the here and some might not make sense, so please let me know if anything needs to be clarified.

I believe the problem is `var select = $('select:has(option:contains(New York))');`... But i am unsure....

Comment: can you add some html as well

Comment: there are missing double quotes in this line: `var select = $('select:has(option:contains(New York))');`. `"New York"`

Comment: I don't have access to the HTML, this is done in an application where HTML is already done and you can make customization via Javascript and jQuery

Comment: @marcel I had already tried that, thanks though

Comment: i created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vfsgfekk/). The `$('select:has(option:contains("New York"))');` part work for me.

Comment: found issue. replace `OptionObj1 [0]` with `OptionObj1.clone()[0]`. updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vfsgfekk/2/)

Comment: what does clone() do?

Comment: Well as the name suggests it creates a copy of the element: https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use this to read the dropdown values?

```
var val1 = $('select.class1').val();
var val2 = $('select.class2').val();
```

I think that way you would not know for sure what values are in dropdowns..

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

You can give the selects `id` or `class` so we can separate selects

```
$('#select1').on('change', function() {
    var sel = obj[$(this).val()];
    $('#select2').empty();
    for(var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
        $('#select2').append($('<option/>').val(sel[i]).text(sel[i]));
    }
});
```

obj is an object containing the information for the second dropdown:

```
var obj = {
    "New York": [
        "New York - Shopping",
        "New York - Nightlife",
        "New York - Sports"
    ],
    "Alabama": [
        "Alabama - Shopping",
        "Alabama - Nightlife",
        "Alabama - Sports"
    ],
    "Texas": [
        "Texas - Shopping",
        "Texas - Nightlife",
        "Texas- Sports"
    ]
};
```

Then when button clicked you just need to get the value of the second dropdown:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    alert($('#select2').val());
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/xdq41q26/3/)